# Интонационное тире перед местоимением

Tags: синтаксис, авторская-пунктуация

*Сначала поешь — ты, а потом уже я.*

Допустима ли постановка тире перед "ты", и необходима ли она во второй части предложения перед "я"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Сначала поешь — ты, а потом уже (поем) я.***

1) Вопрос касается **интонационного тире в неполном предложении**. По правилам это тире обозначает паузу, поэтому нужно составить интонационную схему.

2) Обычно предложения такой структуры пишутся без тире:

*Сначала поешь тЫ, а потом уже Я.* Здесь две фразы, ударение делается на **последнем слове.**

3) Но автор может перенести ударение в первом предложении на наречие ***сначала***, тогда после этого слова делается пауза, которая и обозначается тире.

Во втором предложении такого переноса ударения нет, поэтому нет и тире: СначАла поешь — ты, а потом уже  Я.

Answer (score 0):

*Мне кажется,* что тире не нужно *ни в первой, ни во второй части.* Без слова ***уже*** я бы поставил тире *перед "я",* потому что там ***пропущен глагол "поем"***. А слово ***уже***, по-моему, заполняет паузу перед местоимением, поэтому *тире отпадает.* Но последнее основывается *только на моей интуиции,* не знаю, *согласуется ли это с правилами.*

Comment: Тут вопрос сложный: какой _именно_ глагол имеется в виду. **Поем** или **пою**?

Comment: Точно, для "я" уже "пою"! Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Артём-Артём! Я имела в виду то, что здесь могут быть два РАЗНЫХ глагола: **петь** (поёшь — пою) и **поесть** (поешь — поем).

Comment: Ой, действительно! А я и удивился, почему у Вас "я поём" (это я воспринял через Ё от петь). :)) Интересное наблюдение!!

Comment: Да, простите, не указала смысл глагола( поешь в значении есть).

Comment: Тогда убираю второй вариант.